# How does logical expressions work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, logic

This seems to be a common issue, but I didn't find anything that would help me understand.

I have a bunch of items with introduced member of type bool. Some items have introduced value of true, some of false. So coming from c++ I don't expect this to return 'false' (item.introduced is boolean)

```
if ((show_introduced == "false") && (item.introduced)) {console.log(item.introduced)};
```

but I acctually see 'false' an well as 'true'.

For me it is the same as, which, of course, never output anything.

```
var a = false;
if (true && a) {console.log(a)};
```

Does && works differently in js, or I should find the problem somewhere in the rest of the code?

**EDITED:** Because item.introduced was read from JSON, it was actually a string, so that's the reason why it didn't work.

Comment: `"false"` is a string. Non-empty strings are coerced to `true` when used as a condition, so `true && true` is `true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'false' in quotes makes it a string, which is true. So, "false" != false
write it like

```
(show_introduced === false)
```

**EDIT:**
Falsy values in Javascript:

false (boolean)
"" (an empty string)
0 (zero)
null
undefined
NaN

if you get anything from above, they are falsy value, and everything else if truthy.

Comment: I know, first part of expression is **true**, but I don't understand how it works even when the second part of the expression is **false**. For me it's like `false && true === true` which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: But... it could be that item.introduced is also a string, since it came from JSON. Yep, that was it.

Answer (score 2):

Don't attempt to compare boolean values with true or false, just use them as booleans

```
 if ( showIntroduced )
```

or

```
 if ( ! showIntroduced )
```

Logical operators such as && and || in JavaScript behave as you would expect from C/C++, with the same short-circuit rules.

Comment: the first part is actually a string, I get it as a parameter from url, so I'm comparing it with "false".